# Generated RelativePathProvider doesn't compile when use springfox and org.openapi.generator in SpringBoot web application

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, springfox, openapi-generator

I'm trying to implement a simple spring boot web mvc application, but requirements are:

1. Generate code from api.yaml (openapi 3.0)
2. Generate swagger's code ( I guess it's just a couple of annotations but nevertheless)

But generated code doesn't compile due to generated:

```
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths.RelativePathProvider;
```

in `org/openapitools/configuration/OpenAPIDocumentationConfig.java`

my searching results summarized:

> it's due to old `springfox` version, migrate to `3.0.0`. The RelativePathProvider was replaced by DefaultPathProvider

but I'd already have it originally. And it'seems the generator doesn't know it need to generate `DefaultPathProvider` instead of old `RelativePathProvider`

My `build.gradle.kts` is:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.6"
    id("org.openapi.generator").version("5.3.0")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.31"
}

group = "com.hometask"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    api("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    api("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
    api("org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:0.2.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
val spec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/openapi/api.yml"
val generatedSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/openapi"

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName.set("spring")

    inputSpec.set(spec)
    outputDir.set(generatedSourcesDir)

    apiPackage.set("org.openapi.example.api")
    invokerPackage.set("org.openapi.example.invoker")
    modelPackage.set("org.openapi.example.model")

    configOptions.set(mapOf(
        "dateLibrary" to "java8"
    ))
}

sourceSets {
    getByName("main") {
        java {
            srcDir("$generatedSourcesDir/src/main/java")
        }
    }
}

tasks {
    val openApiGenerate by getting

    val compileJava by getting {
        dependsOn(openApiGenerate)
    }
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: related issue is registred at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/8566 and already solved for one of participants, but i can't understand how...